# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting custom formula not working to same as in cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So have an ArrarFormula in H5 that works exactly the way I want. It searched all the cells in column C and compares them to column A and returns TRUE when column C contains column A. The problem is that I want to move that formula to conditional formating. When I do that it only captures some of the cells, highlighted in Blue. Here is the formula.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA( LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(C5:C, JOIN("|",QUERY(A5:A, "Select A where not A is null")))) > 0))

I have tried copy/pasting to conditional formatting and removing the ArrayFormula and the IFNA. I still get the same results. I know that I can just reference column H in conditional formatting, but I want to try to keep this as clean as possible.

Here is a link to the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xT_U_UZ27X724VAGwUjZ_6fHkE6IaegnbzQTC_kOfEg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample sheet.[Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Conditional formatting may work with arrays but it is best to work with cells (the results). So I suspect a formula as:    = iferror(match(c5,a$5:a,0),0)>0    might do the job in a simple way

Comment: I added a link to the sheet in question. The matching didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your original formula so it can work with conditional formatting:

```
=IFNA( LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(C5, JOIN("|",QUERY($A$5:$A, "Select A where not A is null")))) > 0)
```

- Remove array formula and just use `C5`, the conditional formatting will automatically adjust its row based on your selected `Apply to range`
- You need to fix the range in your `query()` by locking its row and column using `$`

### Output:

[image]

Comment: This worked, Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, if we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)